# Django admin autocomplete_fields saving everything in queryset

Tags: django, django-admin, backend

I am using Django Admin autocomplete_fields to save a bunch of zipcodes. I want to be able to save all the zipcodes in the queryset. Is that possible?

I tried overwriting a bunch of methods but nothing has helped so far.

Comment: You can make a `Zipcode` model, that way `autocomplete` can suggest the zip code. But I'm not sure that I understand what you want to achieve?